# Sources for juxtaposing two opposing approaches to Jewish Halachah

Tags: halacha-theory, talmudic-methodology

Throughout different realms of Halochos I spot two opposing approaches to ruling the practical Halochos - let's call them Absolute and Personal:

- The **Absolute approach** rules/proposes  Halochos that are fixed in measures or actions and do not rely on personal perception.
- The **Personal approach** rules/proposes Halochos that depend on personal feelings or opinions.

For example, in **Hilchos Brochos**, the first approach says Birkas Hamozon is said on a certain measure of bread eaten, while the latter relies on a personal feeling of fullness.

In **Hilchos Kiddush Hachodesh**, G-d shows Moses an exact measure of the New Moon to be Mekadesh on one hand but adds "Lachem" - "you are free to do whatever you please".

In **Hilchos Succah**, we have certain exact measures, 20 Ama or 10 Tfochim, but some refer to personal opinions, like "Holds most of him" or "one who regrets sitting in a Succah is exempt".

In **Hilchos Sanhedrin**, we see that our judicial system is based on clear rules (two witnesses, strict interrogation etc), but on the other hand, the judges are free to execute a person if they just feel so.

In Hilchos Meat and milk, we see that some Halochos are based on fixed amounts of food, while others depend on the subjective taste.

It is important to note that those two approaches are truly intervening in practically any dispute and the final Halacha is often a mix of the two. However, I couldn't relate any specific Rabbis (or schools) to any approach and it appears that the claims are rather random.

This is my personal observation that is consistent with all Masechtos I've learned. I'd like to know if any sources speak of these distinctive approaches in our Halacha?

Comment: How is this two "schools"? Some siurim are absolute, some are subjective, and these are dependent on drashos or Halacha limoshe misini.

Comment: @Mordechai Those are schools of THOUGHT. Of how the Halachah is approached and derived.

Comment: @AlBerko No they aren't schools of thought. They are just two categories of application

Comment: @DoubleAA Ok, then I think he is asking if there are any recognisable patterns in how these categories are applied: if they coalesce around a recognisable set of people or principles or if they are truly random in application.